# Make OpenCV source code. error log: /bin/sh: ./gradlew: No such file or directory

Tags: android, opencv

I compile OpenCV4 source code on my mac, want to compile so library for android develop.

cmake command is work well.

But when I continue `make install`, the error log is print. And the task is almost finish.

```
[ 98%] Built target gen_opencv_java_source
[ 99%] Built target opencv_java
[ 99%] Built target opencv_java_android_source_copy
[ 99%] Building OpenCV Android library project
/bin/sh: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [/opencv/build/outputs/aar/opencv-release.aar] Error 127
make[1]: ***         
[modules/java/android_sdk/CMakeFiles/opencv_java_android.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: `gradlew` script lies on the root of an android project. Is your script running from there?

Comment: No, my current directory is opencv/build, and opencv directory is Opencv source code. so there not have android project

Comment: Your script tries to invoke `gradlew` which is in a project root where gradle wrapper exists. Can you tell me what is the path of script (running `pwd` command on bash)

Comment: Sure, thank you .My directory is "/Users/apple/CWorkSpace/OpenCV/opencv/android_dir" , opencv directory is 
 soft link to "/Users/apple/CWorkSpace/OpenCV/opencv-4.1.0", android_dir is build directory for android target, and I run "cmake **** ..", make , make install

Comment: It's ok ,when i recompile the project. only change some cmake params "-DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=ON -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON", change the OFF to ON

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by change cmake params, the original is

```
-DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF       -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=OFF
```

I change the OFF to ON

```
-DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=ON       -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON
```

Then everything is fun;
My whole procedure is below:

1. mkdir android_build
2. cd android_build
3. call cmake

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON       -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake"       -DANDROID_NDK="/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle"       -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=21       -DANDROID_ABI="arm64-v8a"       -DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=ON       -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON       -DWITH_CUDA=OFF       -DWITH_MATLAB=OFF       -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release       -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=ON       -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON       -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF       -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF       -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF       -DANT_EXECUTABLE="/usr/local/bin/ant"       -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="/Users/apple/CWorkSpace/OpenCV/opencv_contrib/modules/"       -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/Users/apple/CWorkSpace/OpenCV4/android-build/out"  ..
```

4. make
5. make install

finally you find the compile result at android_build/out